# Where to find official DEB packages?

Tags: apt, software-installation, kali-linux

I have a list of packages I wan to download. Since I am new in the *nix world, I don't know where are the **official** places I should go to get the appropriate data. I on a Debian based system (Kali Linux) and every time I google for a package I'm redirected to the RPM version.

Can you explain or redirect me to a **trustworthy place** to search for DEB packages ? Is there ALWAYS an equivalent version of RPM and DEB for a given packages ? If not, could you also redirect me a trustworthy place explaining how to install RPM on Debian *nix ?

Comment: If you're new to the UNIX/Linux world you probably shouldn't be starting with Kali. It's a specialist distribution. Try Mint, Fedora or Ubuntu instead.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to install some packages. You do not have to download them manually, just use the included package manager of your system to install them, they will get downloaded automatically. (e.g. use 'synaptic' as GUI program, or 'apt-get install PROGRAMNAME' for console)

If you really need to download some by hand - try the repository of your distribution, e.g. https://archive.kali.org (/kali/pool/...).

And there is not an RPM for every DEB. Also it is not recommended to use RPM packages with Debian, although some may work, if you use the program 'alien' to work with RPM packages.

Generally you might want to read more about package management in Debian: https://wiki.debian.org/PackageManagement

Answer (score 3):

You should never need to go looking for deb packages on a Debian system.

You can use apt-get or aptitude to search for packages.

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/rn01re01.en.html

There are GUI equivalents as well. In essence the deb system handles, by default trusting and verifying packages and repos.

Of course if you add private repos you need to worry about trusting them, but you have to make that call on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

The `.deb` package for kali linux can be found on the Kali Linux Package Tracker : [here](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/) , to download the `.deb` you need to choose the version then you will be redirected to `http://http.kali.org/pool/` .

You can install an `rpm` package on debian based distro through [`alien`](https://wiki.debian.org/Alien) , but it is not recommended:

> [Install a .RPM in Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/RPM)
>
> To install a .rpm file in a Debian based system you'll need the program Alien. Note that Alien can't work 100% of the time, because rpm and apt are very different.